# What is Globalization and localization concept

Tags: c#

Please someone tell me the concept of Globalization and localization and how they are different. How to implement the concept of Globalization and localization in windows and web application with c#. Looking for good explanation with sample.

Comment: A good first step is to do a little bit of initial research. Then, when/if a SO question is asked, it can focus on specific areas or concepts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scott Hanselman has an [excellent blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx) on this subject. It's more focused on web applications but he exposes some interesting concepts which could be used in desktop applications as well.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [Difference between Globalization and Localization](http://forums.asp.net/p/1032375/1419036.aspx) for the question you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Refering to [ASP.NET Globalization and Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx):

> **Globalization** is the process of
>   designing and developing applications
>   that function for multiple cultures. 
>   **Localization** is the process of
>   customizing your application for a
>   given culture and locale.

The topics in [ASP.NET Globalization and Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx) describe how to create ASP.NET Web applications that can be adapted to different languages and cultures.

Also, the Visual Studio project system provides considerable support for localizing Windows Forms applications. Refer to [Walkthrough: Localizing Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Globalization and localization is mechanism that allow system to work at globally(means every languages) and allowing system to work in local languages that is localization.